# Why won't ajax request POST data come through (in cakePHP)?

Tags: ajax, post, cakephp-2.0

Here's a problem I've fiddled with for more than an hour now and I'm sure there's one simple thing I'm missing.

In `CakePHP 2.x`, I'm trying to send an AJAX request to the `AdministrationController::testAjax()`.

```
function testAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data:{value_to_send:1285}, 
        url:"<?php echo Router::url( array("controller" => "Administration", "action" => "testAjax")); ?>",
        success : function(data) {
           alert(data);

        },
        error : function() {
           alert("false");
        }
    });
}
```

The controller should be able to receive this:

```
public function testAjax() {
    var_dump( $this->request->data('value_to_send') );
    die();
}
```

This returns null, just like this:

```
public function testAjax() {
    var_dump( $_POST );
    die();
}
```

I can't seem to get a hold on the posted value (it does show up in the network tab of the Chrome DevTools), even with this most simplistic example from the `CakePHP` docs and `StackOverflow`. What am I missing?

EDIT:
I did also include the `RequestHandler` as a component:

```
var $components = array("ActionListFactory", "Utilities", "TgiMailer", "RequestHandler");
```

Comment: Please also check url, parameters and output in the network tab.

Comment: @Sehdev Yes I did that, but the URL is correct and the parameters are sent correctly according to the DevTools. If I output something literal like a string in the controllers function, it does show up, so the problem lies at the requesting of the data.